# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails", but version is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Noob following installation directions from [here](http://openconferenceware.org/).

Doing a `bundle install` getting the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":  
  In Gemfile:  
    open_conference_ware (~> 1.0.0.pre) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 4.0.2) ruby
    rails (4.1.8)
```

So I did `sudo gem install rails -v 4.0.2` and now according to `gem list`:

```
rails (4.1.8, 4.0.2)
```

But I still recieve the error!
Doesn't 4.0.2 qualify?
Is there something I need to set to force the proper version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, on both accounts. (Please see **EDIT** below)

When you run `rails new SOMEPROJECT --skip-bundle` it will auto generate a file called `Gemfile`.  (Think of it as a [header file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) as it includes the dependencies for `SOMEPROJECT`  that [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) will setup for you.) When it is generated, it will automatically default to the most current version installed on your system. So you must modify it to point to the proper version of rails:

Change line `gem 'rails', '4.1.8'` to `gem 'rails', '4.0.2'`.

Now you can continue with `bundle install`.

**EDIT**: Because you will likely run into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23857986/1071884) issue later, it is better to regenerate the project altogether by [specifying the version in the `rails new` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452458/1071884):

```
rm -r SOMEPROJECT
rails _4.0.2_ new SOMEPROJECT --skip-bundle
```

Comment: well, glad we could help ;)

Comment: One of those oh-I-should-probably-try-that-out-before-I-hit-submit submissions. Couldn't find a duplicate though, so I answered it. <G>