# Heroku - application error (unable to see app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Hi i have been trying to get to my heroku app but it keeps giving me application error.

Attached is my heroku logs.

```
2014-07-30T05:52:12.995412+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed                                                                                                                                                                                            
2014-07-30T05:52:13.734720+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vast-fortress-4470.herokuapp.com request_id=43cec375-c96a-46c2-adcf-c0a37fb3801e fwd="192.122.131.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=                    
2014-07-30T05:52:14.507679+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vast-fortress-4470.herokuapp.com request_id=86ff6b8e-61f0-4ea8-b0e2-022989592a32 fwd="192.122.131.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=                    
2014-07-30T05:52:14.584623+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-fortress-4470.herokuapp.com request_id=ac5f2cb0-a1f7-4015-8990-6725b82c4f05 fwd="192.122.131.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=         
2014-07-30T05:52:21.245102+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/homr" host=vast-fortress-4470.herokuapp.com request_id=52c4c51f-2f3d-4254-8f9a-675988896758 fwd="192.122.131.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=                
2014-07-30T05:52:21.843978+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-fortress-4470.herokuapp.com request_id=431135aa-9731-4d1d-81d3-cb254e269ae0 fwd="192.122.131.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=         
2014-07-30T05:52:23.903377+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/home" host=vast-fortress-4470.herokuapp.com request_id=bfcc489f-1fab-4c3d-ad7a-1b367755dfc7 fwd="192.122.131.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=                
2014-07-30T05:52:24.521571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-fortress-4470.herokuapp.com request_id=3c145744-7509-4356-850c-5b5002cad995 fwd="192.122.131.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=         
2014-07-30T05:53:29.438004+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/home" host=vast-fortress-4470.herokuapp.com request_id=52240698-37ae-4b3f-9ded-90f7f382304c fwd="192.122.131.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=                
2014-07-30T05:53:30.303500+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-fortress-4470.herokuapp.com request_id=2d436bbf-3384-4820-ba28-259f15185294 fwd="192.122.131.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

And this is my `heroku run rails console`:

```
Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.2353                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `dump_schema_after_migration=' for #<Class:0x007f1af45e9f00> (NoMethodError)                                                                 
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:166:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'                                                                                                                                      
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:165:in `each'                                                                                                                                                                     
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'                                                                                                                                      
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'                                                                                                                                                   
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'                                                                                                                                                    
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'                                                                                                                                         
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'                                                                                                                                                            
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'                                                                                                                                                  
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:322:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'                                                                                                                                                       
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                                                                             
        from /app/app/models/documents.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'                                                                                                                                                           
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'                                                                                                                                                  
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'                                                                                                                                                   
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'                                                                                                                                                           
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:330:in `require_or_load'                                                                                                                                                   
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:289:in `depend_on'                                                                                                                                                         
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:207:in `require_dependency'                                                                                                                                                
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'                                                                                                                                                       
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Have a look with `heroku run rails console` to find out more about the actual error (as `App crashed` isn't really meaningful).

Comment: @ConcurrentHashMap can u help me look at it? ive attached the heroku run rails console part

Comment: Seems to me like you're using some configuration that isn't present in the used Rail version. Maybe this question on SO may help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707102/cannot-run-any-commands-on-my-heroku-app-migrate-console-etc

Comment: I was recently getting almost exact same message.  Did you run "heroku run rake db:migrate" yet?  That is what cleared it up for me.

Comment: @RockwellRice yes i did but it didnt work... :(

Comment: did you type in "heroku run rake"? That is what it tells you to type in in the command line, however, I had to type "heroku run rake db:migrate" for it to work. I just want to make sure because, for me, the wording had different effects (not sure why yet). Heroku run rake fails to migrate but heroku run rake db:migrate worked.

Comment: hi @RockwellRice I did that but it still gave me the same error. the same second error... :/

Comment: Could you post a link to the github repo so I could try to recreate it.