# Migration error on heroku deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `dump_schema_after_migration=' for ActiveRecord:
:Base:Class
```

on

$ heroku run rake db:migrate

I am new to heroku deployment and not able to solve it, please help in solving it
Thanks in advance.

this is what I am actually getting.

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

This is the complete error trace:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.4727
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `dump_schema_after_migration=' for ActiveRecord:
:Base:Class
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_
matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/railtie.
rb:166:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/railtie.
rb:165:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/railtie.
rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_l
oad_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_l
oad_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_l
oad_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_l
oad_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_l
oad_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/railtie.
rb:114:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:
in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:
in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:
in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:
in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:215:i
n `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:229:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:229:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:189:i
n `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:250:i
n `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: are you sure that's the only error you're getting? Can you post full error trace?

Comment: look out for the exact error i have added it in the question.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707102/cannot-run-any-commands-on-my-heroku-app-migrate-console-etc I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Rais 4, just remove below code in your `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

Comment: did you committed the modified file and then deploying?